# Lock/Unlock action / button missing in Google Home app

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a Google action setup to unlock an door via an ESP32. A firebase function handles the Syn, Query and exec steps.

While my door unlocks when I say "open door", I can't see a button under my "Door" icon to lock / unlock. If I click on it, it takes me to the settings page. Am I missing some param in my Sync or Query? Or doesn't Home App UI support this?

[image]

[image]
[image]